# reading edmx, basics

Tags: c#, uml

One simple question about reading edmx file:
If I have on diagram following

```
Account 1 ----- * Invitations
```

that means one to many.

Question is, how can know from this diagram is there `reversing relationship from Invitations to Account?`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relationship either exists or it doesn't - the two tables are either related or they aren't.  So there's no such thing as a "reverse relationship" between them.

However, what I think you're asking for is the existence of **Navigation Properties** from one to the other.  That you can tell by looking at the "Navigation Properties" portion of each table's box.  See [this link](http://thedatafarm.com/blog/data-access/designer-support-for-one-way-navigations-in-entity-framework-4/) for an example with pictures.